# Jest mocked function seems to be a different instance than the function being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm mocking a function that gets used as middleware in an Express app.

`middleware.ts`:

```js
export function middleware1(param: paramType) {
  ...
}
```

In my Jest tests, at the top of the file, I mock `middleware1` as so:

```js
jest.mock('../middleware_path', () => ({
    middleware1: jest.fn(
      _ => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Hello World');
            resolve(next());
          });
        };    
    }),
}));

import * as middlewareUtils from 'middleware'
// This next line is necessary for TypeScript compilation
const mockedMiddlewareUtils = mocked(middlewareUtils);
```

When I call this function by using supertest to hit my API, it **definitely uses this mock implementation.** It prints hello world and everything! However, when I `expect(mockedMiddlewareUtils.middleware1).toHaveBeenCalled();` in my `it` statement, it fails. When I run `middlewareUtils.middleware1` independent of the API call, the `expect` resolves correctly.

The functionality of the mock is clearly propagating correctly but for some reason it seems like there are 2 different instances of the function, 1 that my internal mock is monitoring and 1 that's being used externally. Does this have to do with how I'm exporting the function initially? How it's being consumed by Express? Any additional input would be appreciated.